# Repository não encontrado ao iniciar SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring

Estou executando meu projeto spring boot com conexão ao mysql e esta dando a seguinte falha:

> Description:
>
> Field er in com.eventoapp.controllers.EventoController required a bean
>   of type 'com.eventoapp.repository.EventoRepository' that could not be
>   found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.eventoapp.repository.EventoRepository' in your configuration.

Meu `EventoReposity`:

```
package com.eventoapp.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.eventoapp.models.Evento;

@Repository
public interface EventoRepository extends CrudRepository<Evento, String>{
    Evento findByCodigo(long codigo);
}
```

Meu `EventoController`:

```
package com.eventoapp.controllers;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.eventoapp.models.Evento;
import com.eventoapp.repository.EventoRepository;

@Controller
public class EventoController {

    @Autowired
    EventoRepository er;

    @RequestMapping(value="/cadastrarEvento", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String form() {
        return "evento/formEvento";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/cadastrarEvento", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String form(Evento evento) {

        er.save(evento);
        return "redirect:/cadastrarEvento";
    }

}
```

meu `DataConfiguration`:

```
package com.eventoapp.eventoapp;


import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

@Configuration
public class DataConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eventosapp");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("hednf8iw");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        adapter.setPrepareConnection(true);
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Tem cara que o problema pode ser a entidade Evento. Tem certeza que o @Id de Evento é uma String?

Comment: Ele não esta localizando o repositorio, o que tem a haver com a entidade Evento?

Comment: A classe com o método main está em qual pacote? com.eventoapp?

Comment: Está usando o _starter_ do _data_, `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`? Se não, anote sua `DataConfiguration` com `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Comment: Como está sua entidade `Evento`? Ela está marcada com `@Entity`? Poste o código dela também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem diferentes motivos para este erro ocorrer.

O [mais comum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209023/2387977) é quando a sua classe anotada com `@SpringBootApplication` fica em um pacote (ou módulo) **diferente** do `Repository`.

Para isto, é preciso anotar sua classe `@EnableJpaRepositories`, passando o caminho do pacote onde está o Repository. Exemplo:

```
package com.mensagens; // pacote diferente!

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "br.com.mensagens.repository") // pacote onde está meu repository
@SpringBootApplication
public class MensagensApplication {
```

Este erro também [pode ocorrer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48186530/2387977) se sua entidade `Evento` **não estiver** com a anotação `@Entity`. Este erro, neste caso, é bem confuso, pois você acha que tem algo errado com o seu repositório (ou o local dele) e perde muito tempo até perceber que o problema é na entidade.

Não é o seu caso, mas a falta do `@Repository` na classe também gera o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0):

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "repository") //NA classe EventoappApplication abaixo dos imports

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).